# Using Django F expressions or "extra" SQL to increment value of field based on other related objects

Tags: python, django, postgresql

So, I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid doing the work in Python and use the DB to do the work with the following models:

```
class Draft(models.Model):
    # identity fields
    current_version = models.OneToOneField('app.models.DraftVersion')

class DraftVersion(models.Model):
    # fields which change from version to version
    objects = DraftVersionManager()
    draft = models.ForeignKey(Draft)
    version = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('draft', 'version')


class DraftVersionManager(models.Manager):
    def get_next_version_number(self, draft):
        try:
            return self.filter(draft=draft).order_by('-version')[0].version + 1
        except IndexError:
            return 1
```

So.. Is it possible to do the logic in get_next_version_number inside the db instead of in Python? As shown here for a much simpler example?https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/#f-expressions

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that `F` expressions are necessary in this case. It sounds like this could be accomplished from within *Postgres* as follows:

1. Create a `Version` model which tracks the versions; it's primary key field will be an auto-incrementing sequence you can use as the version number
2. You can `save` a new version through the model in your Django code when you want to create a new version (or do so through pure SQL)
3. Change `DraftVersion`'s `version` field to `ForeignKey` to your `Version` model
4. If you want to *preview* the next version number, it would then be a matter of querying the `Version` model for its max and then adding one, e.g. `Version.objects.all().aggregate(Max('version')) + 1`

**Edit:**

Another option, which may be easier/more flexible, depending on your requirements:

Make the `version` field of the `DraftVersion` model [`AutoField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.AutoField) instead of `PositiveSmallIntegerField`. You can make it a primary key or not, depending on which better fits your needs.

Comment: I don't think this will work as I believe only the primary key may be auto incremented. Unless kevins is okay with globally unique version numbers across all documents.

Comment: From a *Postgres* perspective, any field can be auto-incremented. The same is true in Django, where a field can be made an `AutoField` and doesn't have to be the primary key (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.AutoField).

Comment: Yeah, I don't think this will work. I want my version numbers to reset for each Draft. So, first DraftVersion for a Draft is 1, then 2, then 3.. Also the point of my question is to move the logic into the database. What I have shown works fine for the same purpose, only the calculation is done in Python and first you have to fetch the highest version number from the DB.

Comment: By "reset" it sounds from your example you mean auto-increment, so in that case I'm not sure why setting it as `AutoField` wouldn't work... Then it is *Postgres* handling the version number each time you create a new `DraftVersion`, which you would presumably do with each new `Draft`.